# Setting background for QPushButton in QSS doesn't work

Tags: c++, qt, background-color, qtstylesheets, qpushbutton

I have a `QPushButton` which is a part of `QVBoxLayout` inside a `QWidget` which is a part of `QStackedWidget` (if that may be relevant). I want to set it's background to a color that is slightly different than the background of the `QStackedWidget`.

Because I have many styles in the application I created a QSS file, which is loaded from resources and applied globally to `QApplication`. All the parameters that I set in this file are applied except for `background-color`. (I can change font, padding, border, etc.)

Part of my QSS:

```
#submenuItem {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
    color: white;
    border: none;
    padding-left: 80;
    font-size: 16pt;
    text-align: left;
    height: 60px;
}
```

My button is created like that:

```
QPushButton *btn = new QPushButton(unfolded_menu);
//btn->setStyleSheet("background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);");
btn->setObjectName("submenuItem");
btn->setText("Button text");
```

What is strange is that if I uncomment the 2nd line in C++ code, everything works as expected, but the same line in QSS file has no effect.

What can be the problem? As much as I can achieve the desired look with this workaround, I'd like to have all my styles in a separate file.

Comment: I know that for some properties, updating a widget's property after setting the stylesheet doesn't update the widget style. Try to reapply your stylesheet after setting the object name and see if that changes anything (`qApp->setStyleSheet(qApp->styleSheet())`)

Comment: I had a problem where I had to call `btn->setFlat(true)` to make it work.

Comment: `setFlat` doesn't work @basslo I'm 100% sure only the background parameter doesn't work

Comment: i don't see why it is not working! How are your reading your styleSheet (Qss)? and setting it to the App?  and Is there another styleSheet on one of the other parents (QVboxLayout, the widget containing your button,etc.)?  "submenuItem" is the exact name of your QPushButton? (case sensitive)...

Comment: Found the problem, I had the background set on one of the parent widgets using `setStyleSheet("background-color: ")`. It's either everything in code or everything in QSS I guess.

Comment: No, not really. It is the most specific property that is selected, the background-color, in the Qss is set on the qApp i guess. When you set the same property on your widget it is more specific . See example in the documentation http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/stylesheet-syntax.html#cascading  and i'm sure this section would also be interesting : http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/stylesheet-syntax.html#conflict-resolution .